# Storing log data with mongoose after every creation or update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using nodejs and mongodb, I wan to create a log system that stores data  when mongoose fires queries(creating entry or update fields) so I can keep track of users.

is there a certain plugin for mongoose or I have to do my own system from scratch ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you were looking for?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-history-log

Comment: yes kind of, but I want something automatic, I have many collections , with your solution I have to change all my queries and push to history in every nodejs routes

Comment: I've not used it, but: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-history looks like it could be helpful

Comment: thank you that's what I'm looking for, please do you know if could store just changed data in case of update so I can store just changed fields instead of  the whole Collection object ?

Comment: I haven't used it before so no, sorry

Comment: did you used it? so can I store just changed fields instead of the whole Collection object?